# Javascript Property Functions Without Knowing Properties In Advance

Tags: javascript

I have a simple object:

```
let test = {}
```

Then I add properties:

```
test.a = document.getElementById("element")
```

I'm trying to figure out, if it's even possible, how to add default functions to each of these properties *without knowing the properties in advance*.

For example, I want to bind multiple event listeners like this:

```
test.a.addMultipleEventListeners(args)
```

If creating functions automatically for every property is possible it would make a great pattern in the project I am working on.

Am I way off base here or missing something obvious?

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: what is `addMultipleEventListeners`?

Comment: It could be anything, that's just an example I provided.  I want to be able to create default functions for any property added to test.  Problem is, I don't know what those properties are ahead of time.  Might not be possible.

Comment: ``Object.keys(object_name)`` would list out all the properties in the object. You can loop through the properties and add your functions.

Comment: I've read this multiple, multiple times now and I have no idea what you're asking. Can you create properties on the fly, yes. Can you call methods on the objects that these properties represent...yes. What is your actual question?

Comment: So you just want to list the properties of an object?

Comment: I revised my question slightly, sorry for the confusion.  I want to create the property's functions automatically for any property added (without knowing them in advance)

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't help. What does "creating functions automatically for every property" mean?

Comment: @BillKervaski Does my answer help? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Perhaps you should of understood the question before answering @hev1?

Comment: If later in the code a new property is added to test, I'd like that property to get any custom functions automatically.  So basically, a default property constructor where any property inherits all the functions.

Comment: that sounds like a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), maybe. So if I create `x.a` and assign is a function, `x.a.y = () => {}`. Then when I create `x.b` it should automagically have `x.b.y`? What happens if you I do `x.b.z = () => {}`. Should I then be able to do `x.a.z()`? Possibility is one thing, but this sounds horribly confusing.

Comment: Or you could maybe clone the object then extend it? It really depends what you want, which is still not clear

Comment: Something like [hev1's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777664/1913729)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to handle all properties that are set.

```js
const obj = new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
    set(obj, prop, value) {
       value.addMultipleEventListeners = 
       (events, fn)=>events.forEach(event=>value.addEventListener(event,fn));
       return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    }
});
obj.a = document.querySelector('#a');
obj.a.addMultipleEventListeners(['mousedown', 'mouseover'], e=>console.log(e.type));
```

```html
<div id="a" style="border: 1px solid red; text-align: center;">Click or hover over me!</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. Though I think what OP is trying to do looks more like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qdsvkp3n/